# Ansible with_items loop over groups, defined as a list

Tags: loops, ansible

I am trying to modify my ufw  firewall playbook, so it would accept list of host groups from inventory, that will be allowed to connect.
It works fine for one group, but that's just not flexible enough for my needs. 
But when I try this, it just won't work (I didn't expect it to work, but I just don't know, how to do it):

```
- name: allow only specified groups of servers to connect to any port
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    src: "{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']}}"
  with_items:
    - groups.{{ ufw_allow_groups }}
```

Variable is defined as a list:

```
ufw_allow_groups:
  - group_of_hosts1
  - group_of_hosts2
```

Error message:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: \"hostvars['groups.['group_of_hosts1', 'group_of_hosts']']\" is undefined
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish that?
Thanks for any input!

Comment: Your variable is `ufw_allow_groups`, then why you have `groups.{{ ufw_allow_groups }}` for looping? Even if that is the case, it should be `{{ groups.ufw_allow_groups }}`

Comment: I  just tried that, but now it complaints about dictionary attribute  missing. fatal: [shtest.phplist.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'ufw_allow_groups'"}   Perhaps I'll try to play with dictionary variable instead of list.

Comment: I gave that comment in an assumption of how your variable looked like. Post your vars!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think working with only one group is flexible enough.  Simply make supergroups.

So, let's say you have three groups, two of which you want to be allowed to connect:

```
[group1]
host1_1
host1_2

[group2]
host2_1
host2_2

[group3]
host3_1
host3_2
```

Now, you only want group1 and group3 hosts to be able to connect.  Add a supergroup:

```
[ufw_allow_groups]
[ufw_allow_groups:children]
group1
group3
```

Comment: I thought of something similar,  but  the list of groups needs to be in host_vars  or group_vars, because there's plenty of nodes and there will be different firewall settings for them.

Comment: Different firewall settings for each node?